# Customised TabLayout: notifydatasetchanged revert custom view of tabs back to the default

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Below is the result I am currently getting.

[image: Result]

The expected result should be three of them behave as the third tab.

This is how I setup my tab layout.

Reusable method to add fragment to view pager / tab layout.

```
public void addFragmentToViewPager(Fragment fragment, String title, int imageRes) {

    FragmentViewPagerAdapter fragmentViewPagerAdapter =
            (FragmentViewPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();

    int position = fragmentViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment, title);

    fragmentViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    View tabItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_item_child, null);

    RoundedImageView roundImageView = (RoundedImageView) tabItemView.findViewById(R.id.childitem_riv);

    roundImageView.setImageResource(imageRes);

    TextView textView = (TextView) tabItemView.findViewById(R.id.childitem_tv_title);

    textView.setText(title);

    TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(position);

    if (tab != null) {
        Log.d(TAG,tab.getText()+"");
        tab.setCustomView(tabItemView);
    }
}
```

How I add fragment :

```
    getView().addFragmentToViewPager(new ReusableMomentFragment(), "One", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    getView().addFragmentToViewPager(new ReusableMomentFragment(), "Two", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    getView().addFragmentToViewPager(new ReusableMomentFragment(), "Three", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

And my FragmentViewPagerAdapter :

```
public class FragmentViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public FragmentViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public int addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

    return getCount() -1 ;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}
```

Result for Log.d in addFragmentToViewPager :

```
04-27 06:49:39.874 14334-14334/com.zxc.zxczxc D/MomentFragment: One
04-27 06:49:39.877 14334-14334/com.zxc.zxczxc D/MomentFragment: Two
04-27 06:49:39.878 14334-14334/com.zxc.zxczxc D/MomentFragment: Three
```

**Update :**

I found out that, after

> fragmentViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

called, the tab layout will be changed to back to default view. Is there any way to prevent `notifyDataSetChanged()` not to affect the tab layouts' custom view? Because my tab layout tabs are set on the go (app will fetch the tab content from server and set it up) so my idea is to setup the viewpager first :

```
FragmentViewPagerAdapter fragmentViewPagerAdapter =
            new FragmentViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentViewPagerAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Then add in the fragment by using :

```
    public void addFragmentToViewPager(Fragment fragment, String title, int imageRes) {

    FragmentViewPagerAdapter fragmentViewPagerAdapter =
            (FragmentViewPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();

    int position = fragmentViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment, title);

    View tabItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_item_child, null);

    RoundedImageView roundImageView = (RoundedImageView) tabItemView.findViewById(R.id.childitem_riv);

    roundImageView.setImageResource(imageRes);

    TextView textView = (TextView) tabItemView.findViewById(R.id.childitem_tv_title);

    textView.setText(title);

    TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(position);

    if (tab != null) {
        Log.d(TAG,tab.getText()+"");
        tab.setCustomView(tabItemView);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Comment: Yeap, and I posted the solution below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739721/7130559

Comment: Please do not hesitate to upvote my answer if it helps you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly simple.

We should understand how [PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) works. By calling it, the tabs will be reloaded. The method I posted is to change the layout externally. Which means the custom layout will be reverted back to default.

So the solution is to add the fragments to `fragmentViewPager` first, follows by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`, and customise your layout.

You should only customize your layout after calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Material Design `TabLayout`

in gradle:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

in code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("ONE");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("TWO");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_call, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("THREE");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout:

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Output:

[image]

Here is the Detail [Implementation](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the I need the image to be in a rounded image view, and also the image will be downloaded by Picasso on runtime, so I need to set the tab view in a custom view, including the rounded image view, the answer above is to set the image in the tab itself not on custom view (tab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds). Anyway, thanks for your reply.